# what does linear regression actually mean?

Tags: regression

Wikipedia gives the following definition for linear regression:

> In statistics, linear regression is an approach for modeling the
>   relationship between a scalar dependent variable y and one or more
>   explanatory variables (or independent variable) denoted X. The case of
>   one explanatory variable is called simple linear regression.

What does the name actually mean?  I.e. what do the 'linear' and 'regression' parts of the name actually stand for?

Comment: Popular question without like 7+ upvotes, nice work guys I like this SE. This isn't a question that shows research effort. (I'm totally serious.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Linear* means you are estimating a relationship by a straight line, or more correctly by linear multiples of the explanatory variables and a constant.

*Regression* is related to *regression to the mean*: the expected height of children of tall parents (adjusted for gender) estimated from linear regression is above average but lower than the heights of the parents; this has echoes of eugenics. Using [Francis Dalton's data as illustrated in Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LinearRegressionWithGaltonsData02.png) you get something like this

[image]

Comment: Just to emphasize the linear part, linear regression is linear in the parameters not necessary the data. That is the model y= $\beta_{0} +\beta_{1}x^{100} +\epsilon$ is a linear model but the model y= $\beta_{0} +\beta_{1}^{2}x +\epsilon$ is not.

Comment: Can you explain your funky graph please?

Comment: @AlecTeal: It is not my graph, but heights are in inches and the graph type is a sunflower plot with strokes coming out of each point (strictly speaking a range) representing the number of observations there. Look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistData/HistData.pdf under "Galton" for some example code

Answer (score 2):

"Linear" refers to the type of the model,
$$
y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 +\ldots + \beta_m x_m.
$$
to understand the meaning of "linear" without going to higher dimensions, let's have just one $x$ and assume $\beta_0=0$. Then above formula reduces to,

$$
y= \beta_1 x_1
$$
as you see this is a line with slop of $\beta_1$ in 2D space. This models simply means, by knowing a coefficient, $\beta_1$ and having some values for $x_1$, then you can find (maybe predict with some uncertainty) the value of the left hand side (usually called response variable). This procedure is called regression in literature.